# ¿Como saber a través de la api de facebook si una imagen una url compartida en facebook este correcta?

Tags: facebook-api

Hay ciertos post's en mi sitio basado en question2answer que al ser compartidos en facebook su imagen no se recupera y se ve como en la foto siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he verificado las etiquetas open-graph y me he cerciorado que las imágenes cumplan con las recomendaciones de facebook pero a aun así hay post's con imágenes que tienen problemas para ser recuperadas por el analizador de url de facebook.

La idea es correr un script que haga esas validaciones y obtener una lista de posts con problemas la compatibilidad de la imagen.

El script debe poder obtener esta información aun si la url no halla sido compartida en facebook.

Todo esto es posible hacerlo con el analizador de url compartido de facebook(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) la idea seria poder tener un script para automatizar este proceso.

Yo revise la api graph de facebook en la seccion de la url(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/url) pero no logre conseguir informacion acerca de la imagen y para que la api te pueda dar informacion acerca de las etiqueta og de la url, esta tiene que haber sido compartida previamente, por lo que aqui me quede en un callejon sin salida.

Esta imagen da un ejemplo de la consulta que realice en la api para obtener datos de las etiquetas de open graph, con el fin de capturar url's con problemas en la imagen, pero no se como decirle a la api que analice la url, aún si está no ha sido compartida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que mis preguntas en realidad son:

**¿hay algún modo de saber a través de la api de facebook si la imagen presente en una url compartida, es correcta o tiene problemas?**

**¿Hay alguna forma mediante la api de facebook de mandar analizar una url, si esta aún  no ha sido compartida y comprobar que sus etiquetas han sido analizadas correctamente?** sobre todo la imagen que a veces es la que da problemas.

Comment: probá con `&scrape=true` que está en el ejemplo de update url, tal vez debas consultar la info y si no hay enviar el update para luego consultar nuevamente ( es el flow manual del developers debug pulsando botones )

Comment: Si ya probe con `&scrape=true` y no me funciona para analizar una url si no ha sido compartida, creo que este parametro sirve para resetear la cache de los datos asociados a una url, pero no para analizar una url si no ha sido compartida, voy a revisar update url que no lo he estudiado bien.